# PATCH request seems like a step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context, use-reducer

Hey folks really hope someone can help me here. I'm successfully updating my object in my mongo cluster, it updates but it does not render that update straight away to the browser. It will only update after a reload or when I run my update function again, it doesn't fetch that update straight away and I can't understand why. Does anyone have any suggestions?
I'm using context and reducer.

PlantDetails

```
 import { usePlantsContext } from "../hooks/usePlantsContext";
    import formatDistanceToNow from "date-fns/formatDistanceToNow";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import CalendarComponent from "./CalendarComponent";
    const PlantDetails = ({ plant }) => {
      const [watered, setWatered] = useState(false)
      const [newWaterDate, setNewWaterDate] = useState("")
      const { dispatch } = usePlantsContext();
      const handleClick = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("/api/plants/" + plant._id, {
          method: "DELETE",
        });
        const json = await response.json();
    
        if (response.ok) {
          dispatch({ type: "DELETE_PLANT", payload: json });
        }
      };
      const updatePlant = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        plant.nextWaterDate = newWaterDate
    
        const response = await fetch("api/plants/" + plant._id, {
          method: "PATCH",
          body: JSON.stringify(plant),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        const json = await response.json()
    
        if(response.ok) {
          dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PLANT", payload: json })
        }
        console.log('updated')
        setWatered(false)
      }
      return (
        <div className="plant-details">
          <h4>{plant.plantName}</h4>
          <p>{plant.quickInfo}</p>
          <p>
            {formatDistanceToNow(new Date(plant.createdAt), { addSuffix: true })}
          </p>
          <span onClick={handleClick}>delete</span>
          <div>
            <p>next water date: {plant.nextWaterDate}</p>
            <input onChange={(e) => setNewWaterDate(e.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={updatePlant}>update</button>
            <input value={watered} type="checkbox" id="toWater" onChange={() => setWatered(true)}/>
            <label  for="toWater">watered</label>
            {watered && <CalendarComponent updatePlant={updatePlant} setNextWaterDate={setNewWaterDate}/>}
          </div>
          
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default PlantDetails;
```

Context which wraps my

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'

export const PlantsContext = createContext()

export const plantsReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_PLANTS':
            return { 
                plants: action.payload 
            }
        case 'CREATE_PLANT':
            return {
                plants: [action.payload, ...state.plants]
            }
        case 'DELETE_PLANT':
            return {
                plants: state.plants.filter((p) => p._id !== action.payload._id)
            }
        case 'UPDATE_PLANT':
            return {
                plants: state.plants.map((p) => p._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : p )
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const PlantsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(plantsReducer, {
        plants: null
    })

    return (
        <PlantsContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
            { children }
        </PlantsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

My plantController (update)

```
const updatePlant = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No plant" })
    }

    const plant = await Plant.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {
        ...req.body
    })

    if (!plant) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No plant" })
    }
    res.status(200)
    .json(plant)
}
```

Home component

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import PlantDetails from "../components/PlantDetails";
import PlantForm from "../components/PlantForm";
import CalendarComponent from "../components/CalendarComponent";
import { usePlantsContext } from "../hooks/usePlantsContext";
const Home = () => {
  const { plants, dispatch } = usePlantsContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlants = async () => {
      console.log("called");
      // ONLY FOR DEVELOPMENT!
      const response = await fetch("/api/plants");
      const json = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_PLANTS", payload: json });
      }
    };
    fetchPlants();
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="plants">
        {plants &&
          plants.map((plant) => <PlantDetails key={plant._id} plant={plant} />)}
      </div>
      <PlantForm />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you modify the props here? `plant.nextWaterDate = newWaterDate`

Comment: Modify here because the new value will be 'newWaterDate' value, that's the update I want to change

Comment: Modifying props can lead to unexpected behaviours like yours. You should create a new object

Comment: Ok I will try that, and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.
You you could spot anything in my repo please let me know

Comment: https://github.com/Fluffy-Lion/myPlants/tree/main/frontend

Comment: Please show the parent of `PlantDetails` as well

Comment: my Home component, just added

Comment: I looked at your repository and I have no idea what is wrong, sorry

Comment: Thanks for looking, really appreciate it. I'm confused as hell. It updates my cluster and fires the request, but state almost doesn't recognise it until there is another change or after a reload.

Answer (score 0):

My patch requests were going through smoothly but my state would not update until I reloaded my page. It was not returning the document after the update was applied.

[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#:~:text=%3B%20//%2059-,You,-should%20set%20the](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#:%7E:text=%3B%20//%2059-,You,-should%20set%20the)